# How can I pass PHP GET URL variables to open a window with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events, javascript-framework

I'd like to pass a PHP get variable from a link to Javascript so I can open a new smaller window with the appropriate content from the value passed to the URL .. I tried to do that below and I couldn't ... I'd really appreciate your assistance. The code below generates image hyperlinks that each have their ids from the database, so when the image is clicked on, a new window should be open but the ID should be passed to the javascript window.open method ... I tried to do that with AJAX to load the content according to the get variable but I couldn't do it!

```
<?php
require('../database/connect.php');
database_connect();
$query = "select * from Entertainers";
$result = $connection->query($query);
$row_count =$result->num_rows;

for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++)
  {
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();


?>
<?php  echo "<a href='' onclick='window.open(profile.php?id=".$row['ID'].")'><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>"; } ?>
```

Comment: why not `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){}` ??

Comment: the last matching curly brace is at the end of the script ..I'd like the window open with the passed in variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to quote the url in the Javascript `open` function. Also, did you consider using [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) for outputting?

```
$link =
'<a href="" onclick="window.open(\'profile.php?id=%d\')">'
. '<img src="../%s" width="100" height="100" /></a>' . PHP_EOL;

for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    printf($link,$row['ID'],$row['Picture']);
}
```

`%d` represents a decimal and `%s` represents a string in the above string (hence the `$link`). **Another tip:** if you have no particular reason to use the for loop, using a while loop instead will make your code cleaner and shorter.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf($link,$row['ID'],$row['Picture']);
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS.. THAANK YOU !!!! you really saved me .. How can I accept your answer ... I'd like us to keep in touch .. I am from Los Angeles , CA

Comment: How can I make that opened window a with of 200 and 100 ??

Comment: how can I make that window a width of 100 and height of 200 .. a separated opened window ??  I'd like to have that effect from the code that you already gave to me ..

Comment: @GuyRwayitare No problem. Most of the time we spend for debugging is caused by annoying typos or little syntax problems like these. You can accept an answer by the checkmark under the downvote arrow, on the left to the answer. [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) to see the available function parameters for the `window.open` function, which includes the window size.

Comment: your answer has been accepted my friend .. I would really appreciate if you could help me out on this one as well .. I've been trying to pass a PHP GET variable from a link to AJAX so the the content can be loaded on the same page but I haven't been able to receive help ... Here is the pastebin link .. how can I achieve that and pass the get variable to the AJAX .. link http://pastebin.com/VKg72rB3

Comment: This one doesn't work for same reason .. the link from pastebin .. the content doesn't reload in the same page ...

Comment: @GuyRwayitare You mean you can't open the link? It opens just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

When your script renders the HTML on the page the `URL` parameter to `window.open` is *not* being rendered as a `string`.

What your code currently renders on the page:

```
<a href='' onclick='window.open(profile.php?id={some_id})'><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>"; } ?>
```

The URL `profile.php?id={some_id}` is *not* a string when it is being parsed at the client.

Try this:

```
<?php  echo "<a href='' onclick=\"window.open('profile.php?id=" . $row['ID'] . "');\"><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>"; ?>
```

Comment: @GuyRwayitare That's strange. All I did was add quotes around your URL in the JS call. Are you getting any error? inhan's solution above is cleaner but it is essentially the same.

Comment: @GuyRwayitare I hope you have used the code line in the context of your original code and not dumped that line on a new page because I left an ending curly brace in there that will cause issues. I'll modify the answer.